# why content uri is not working in this case

Tags: android

```
Uri sare_sms = Uri.parse("content://contacts/");    
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(sare_sms, null, null, null, null);

TextView txt = ( TextView ) findViewById (R.id.txt);
txt.setText( new Integer(c.getColumnCount()).toString());
```

this code is not working

but

```
Uri sare_sms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox/");
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(sare_sms, null, null, null, null);

TextView txt = ( TextView ) findViewById (R.id.txt);
txt.setText( new Integer(c.getColumnCount()).toString());
```

and this working correctly why ?

& i have included

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" 
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `content://contacts/people` to get contacts info